# how can i use the camara busy with opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I'm working with 2 `opencv` modules in diferents file in `python` and I'm trying to capture frames continuously with a module, but when running the other module how could I capture the frame or have the properties of the camera and use it to capture the frame.

IS it posible to make a general file and get the frame from the camera on from others files?